# How to know if there is any Ajax Request and ajax Success

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I wonder how can I code this:

```
//if there is any ajax request
   $("#loader").css("display","block");
//on success:
    $("#loader").css("display","none");
```

**Note :**
I am not going to code it again and again in my each ajax request function.
I want it generic so that my script knows if there is any ajax request  do `$("#loader").css("display","block");` and if there is any ajax success do  `$("#loader").css("display","none");`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magical thing you are looking for is [jQuery.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [jQuery.ajaxStop()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/). You might also find [jQuery.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) useful.

Example:

```
$("#loader").ajaxStart(function() {
   $(this).show();
}).ajaxStop(function() {
   $(this).hide();
});
```

You should use the `hide()` and `show()` methods instead of changing the `display` CSS attribute.

Comment: if i have two loaders in one page than ??

Comment: @FawadGhafoorasXaineeKhan: Do you want to show one per AJAX request or both or what? You'll have to explain what you're doing a little more. You can show and hide a loader on an individual `$.ajax()` call if you'd like, so let me know if that's what you're after.

Comment: i have one page in which there are 2 ajax requests and also 2 loaders.i wana show one loader per ajax request

Comment: @FawadGhafoorasXaineeKhan: You could show a loader in the `beforeSend()` event and then hide it in the `error()` or `success()` callback in your `$.ajax()` call. You define `beforeSend()` just like you would `success()`.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [`$.ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`$.ajaxEnd`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) when you wire up your app in $.document(ready):

```
$.ajaxStart(function(){
  $("#loader").css("display", "block");
})
.ajaxStop(function(){
  $("#loader").css("display", "none");
});
```

**UPDATE** forgot about ajaxStop...@Cory's answer reminded me.  Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

These other solutions are great but I am not sure they address your concern of calling your `$("#loader")` CSS changes on **start** and **success**.

May be something like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {

  // do something on start
  $("#loader").css("display","block");

}).ajaxError(function(e, xhr, settings) {
  // do something on error
  $("#loader").css("display","none");

}).ajaxSuccess(function() {

  // do something on success
  $("#loader").css("display","block");

});
```

Check out this properly working example: http://jsbin.com/ocovoq/3/edit#preview

Answer (score 1):

If you fire off two or three ajax calls, ajaxStop will only fire when the last one is done.

```
var isMakingAjaxCall;

$(document).ready(function () {

    // Loading Screen for Ajax Calls
    $("#loader").hide();
    $("#loader").ajaxStart(function () {
        isMakingAjaxCall = true;
        RepositionLoading();
        $("#loader").fadeIn();
    });
    $("#loader").ajaxStop(function () {
        $("#loader").fadeOut();
        isMakingAjaxCall = false;
    });
});

function RepositionLoading() {
    $("#loader").css('left', "20px");
    $("#loader").css('top', "20px");
};
```