# How to know if there if any xhr request made and success on document using javascript

Tags: javascript

My problem is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9740939/how-to-know-if-there-is-any-ajax-request-and-ajax-success) question but I need an answer in javascript. It is very simple to achieve this in jquery. I also debug the jquery file but it seems more confusing to me.

```
//if there is any ajax request
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display="block";
//on success:
   document.getElementById("loader").style.display="none";
```

Comment: can you show the code thats firing the ajax? although your link answer is using jquery, a native solution using a httpRequestObject would still use the callbacks for success

Comment: Actually we are submitting a form using iframe

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20689481/recreating-jquerys-ajaxstart-and-ajaxcomplete-functionality

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567114/how-to-make-an-ajax-call-without-jquery

Comment: @atmd It is too deep for me now

Comment: @dec I think now I can at least start